# Objective C Converting NSString to UTF8 with padding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am implementing AES decoder, for creating IV and key, the algorithm is such that

IV Key's 16 bytes：the first 16 bytes of ProductID.getBytes("UTF-8")

```
            （If there are no enough bytes,      

            make up to 16 bytes at right by 0x32)
```

and my code for padding

```
- (char*)paddedStringFromString:(NSString *)string withLength:(NSUInteger)length{
    const char *stringC = [string UTF8String];
    char * output;
    output = malloc(length+1);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i < string.length) output[i] = stringC[i];
        else output[i] = 0x32;
    }
    return output;
}
```

But I am not getting the right result. Is my approach for padding is right. Please help

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have non-ASCII characters in your NSString, the resulting UTF8 string will be longer than the NSString.  I'd concatenate 16 blanks to the NSString, convert to UTF8, and then take the first 16 bytes of that.

Comment: The other way I might do it is to use `strlen` to determine the length of the UTF8, copy that to the buffer for max 16 chars, then pad as needed.

Comment: well as of now in my testing, the value of IV is @"123", so in your approach if I concatenate 16 blanks, but i need to add padding with 0x32(UTF8)... so in nsstring how can i do that

Comment: 32 decimal is blank.  0x32 is "2".  I strongly suspect that you're supposed to pad with blanks, not the character "2".

Comment: its 0x32 only, and its working with hard code value, my code for conversion is proper, the problem was at some end, is there a proper method to interconvert hexadecimal to utf8

Comment: If it really is 0x32 (I still doubt it) append "2" characters.

Comment: yah it is , there decryption algorithm is like that only, and it is working fine :), thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

I think the args length and string.length are not the same, right?